# Merge excel workbooks, name sheets after file names

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to merge multiple excel files into one workbook. I'm struggling to add some code to name newly created sheets after file names they were taken from.

Please help.

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
    Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook

    fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

    If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

        If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
            countFiles = 0
            countSheets = 0

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

            For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                countFiles = countFiles + 1

                Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(filename:=fnameCurFile)

                For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                    countSheets = countSheets + 1
                    wksCurSheet.Copy After:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
                Next

                wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

            Next

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

            MsgBox "Procesed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't see any code to add sheet names - what have you tried?

Comment: Where is the difficulty? Directly after the copy, find the last sheet of `wbkCurBook` and rename it to `fnameCurFile`, there is a `Sheets.Name` property.

Comment: You're going to hit issues using the filename of a file as a sheet name though. @Pᴇʜ is right, you just need to use the `.Name` property but you're going to have to: **1**. Get the filename without the full path and **2**. Clean the filename of characters not allowed in a sheet name, such as `[` and `]` which can form part of a filename and **3** add a numbering system if more than one sheet comes from the same filename.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are copying many sheets from each file - so you can't just name the sheets after the source file name. And if you append the filename to the existing sheet name you may hit the 31 character limit on sheet names. Assuming that isn't a problem you would do:

After

```
 wksCurSheet.Copy After:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
```

Add

```
 wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count).name = left(wksCurSheet.name & wbkSrcBook.name,31)
```

But I suspect this will fail to produce sufficiently different names unless your files are very distinct